# unity3d GameObject is already being activated or deactivated

Tags: unity-game-engine

In Unity, at runtime, I am detaching a child object from its parent when it is disabled. An error is being logged to the console "GameObject is already being activated or deactivated".

Apparently this is because I am changing the parent in the same frame that the child is being deactivated. This happens even though I see in the hierarchy that the child is successfully detached. So, from my point, everything worked fine.

So, does anyone know if this is just a spurious error, is it something I need to actually care about?

Comment: Are you doing this with the `OnDisabled` function?

Comment: I believe Telepathy doesn't work with Unity at the moment. So would you like to share the code that you are using?

Comment: It is pretty much exactly as it sounds like

`obj.transform.parent = null;`
If you do that the same frame as `obj.SetActive(false);` the error is logged

Comment: Debug.Log before and after each line and see if they are called in the right order.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have something odd going on because such an error does not happen, and here how you can prove it.

Take this script:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class SyncTest : MonoBehaviour {

    private Transform cube;

    void Start () {
        cube = transform.GetChild(0);   // No tests as I know it's there
    }

    private void OnMouseUpAsButton()
    {
        cube.parent = null;
        gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }

}
```

Then create a sphere and put a cube as its child like in this:

[image: The sphere and its child]

Then attach the script to the sphere:

[image: Script attached to the sphere]

Run the scene and just click on the sphere, the result is that the sphere disappears and the cube stays on and is no longer a child, no errors at all are produced:

[image]

I believe you have some synchronization problem, running the two commands in some odd fashion, most likely you are calling the `obj.SetActive(false);` twice in a row.